# Iterate a hash of nested arrays/hashes/strings and perform some logic on them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to loop through a hash that contains a mix of nested object types. E.g.

```
{
  "a" => "1",
  "b" => ["1", "2"],
  "c" => {"d" => "1", "e" => {"f" => ["1", "2", {"g" => ["x", "y", "1"]}]}}
}
```

and transform all string values to integers, given that they consist of numbers only. So they should match `/^\d+$/`.

But the important part is the iteration part.

**How do I find all the values of key/value pairs as well as all values inside arrays, so I can manipulate them?**

It's a bit similar to the [deep_symbolize_keys](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) method, only here I'm interested in everything else that hash keys.

My own implementation goes like this, but it's long and I may not have catched all edge cases:

```
def all_to_i(x)
  if x.is_a?(Hash)
    x.each do |k, v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        all_to_i(v)
      elsif v.is_a?(Array)
        x[k] = v.map { |v2| all_to_i(v2) }
      elsif v.is_a?(String)
        if v.scan(/^\d+$/) != []
          x[k] = v.to_i
        else
          x[k] = v
        end
      end
    end
  elsif x.is_a?(Array)
    x.map { |x2| all_to_i(x2) }
  elsif x.is_a?(String)
    if x.scan(/^\d+$/) != []
      x.to_i
    else
      x
    end
  end
end

# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>[1, 2], "c"=>{"d"=>1, "e"=>{"f"=>[1, 2, {"g"=>["x", "y", 1]}]}}}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Apologies, I have made some edits, so the question is highlighted inside it's own sentence.

Comment: `x.match? /^\d+$/` gives you a boolean directly. I have other style suggestions, but this isn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackoverflow.com) is it?

Comment: Overall, looks good to me. Can be improved, yes, but should be more or less functional. I assume you have specs for this? If not, you should. :)

Comment: @MarkThomas thanks for the input, it's of course better to just look for a match. Thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, I would just think it could be done with much fewer lines. The function is repeating itself a lot.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: yes. Here's where specs come in. You write a spec for every case you can think of, and then start refactoring the code. Specs will tell you when you break stuff. If they're still green and code looks better, then good job :)

Comment: Got my codereview link wrong above. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chris/b4138603a8fe17e073c6bc073eb17785).